# zero-copy from SocketChannel to SocketChannel

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel, zero-copy

With Java's NIO API, is it possible to implement a zero-copy data transfer from one socket to another? I'm aware of `FileChannel::transferTo()` which does this from file to socket, but there isn't a `transferTo()` method on `SocketChannel`.

Comment: I think this is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901549/1602555